# overflow: scroll with content position: absolute

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to achieve a slideUp into view effect, with scrolling. This is exactly like any console (shell, browser javascript, any REPL) that we all use multiple of everyday, but with a little animation flair. In the fiddle I have an example of the desired effect first, and the desired `overflow: scroll` second.

I have been unable to get both pieces working together. I have seen similar examples here on SO, but none with a fiddle, nor answered!

Illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/n8tqw/

Comment: The effect seems to work fine in both boxes, it's just that in the bottom one it doesn't automatically scroll down when a line is added; is that the problem?

Comment: The 2nd is not bottomed out (bottom: 0 needs position: absolute to work in this case), so the 'pushing up' isn't possible. I know about scrollHeight, but the first added elements won't feel like they're 'pushing up' until the scrollable container's height is filled. Not exactly what I want.

Comment: It's very common for REPLs to build from the top down and for things to "push up" starting only when the container is full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was quite an interesting puzzle, but I finally got it to work.  Essentially you need a relative container that extends to the height of the entire absolute container, and then have another container (relative or static) with the set height (200px).  For whatever reason, browsers don't consider "off the top" absolute content to be outside of the scroll area:

http://jsfiddle.net/n8tqw/1/

```
$('#add-one').click(function() {

   var $p = $('<p class="content">' + number++ + '</p>')
        .appendTo('#from-bottom');
    $("#beholder").height($("#from-bottom").height());
    $("#scrollable-container").scrollTop($("#beholder").height());
    $p.hide().slideDown();
});
```

The new paragraph cannot be hidden immediately because the relative container needs to get the total height, and if it's hidden the new paragraph's height won't be added.  Similarly, `scrollable-container`'s scrollTop will be a bit off if it's hidden.  Not hiding it initially seems to be unnoticeable to a user, though.

Comment: very nice! exactly what I wanted